# How can I increment a counter once only, no matter how many times a Jradiobutton is clicked

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a set of questions, and I want to count the number of correct answeres. My problem here is that it increments on every click on a correct answer.

I am trying to count the correct answers chosen by a user, but I dont know how to make  it count only once, and not increment the counter every time the button is pressed. 
I dont want it to increment on every click on correct answers, since that will mess up the counter.

So for example if  "A" is the correct answer, and the user clicks on "A" then chooses "B" , then chooses "A" again, in the same question. The counter will be at 2, while I want it to be at 1

```
//Question 2
        JLabel lblWhatProtects = new JLabel("2) What protects the brain?");
        lblWhatProtects.setForeground(new Color(199, 21, 133));
        lblWhatProtects.setBounds(301, 46, 242, 23);
        panel.add(lblWhatProtects);
        lblWhatProtects.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.BOLD, 15));

        JRadioButton rdbtnSkull = new JRadioButton("Skull");
        rdbtnSkull.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        rdbtnSkull.setBounds(328, 79, 127, 25);
        panel.add(rdbtnSkull);
        rdbtnSkull.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));

        JRadioButton rdbtnHeart = new JRadioButton("Heart");
        rdbtnHeart.setBounds(328, 109, 127, 25);
        rdbtnHeart.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(rdbtnHeart);


        JRadioButton rdbtnKidneys = new JRadioButton("Kidneys");
        rdbtnKidneys.setBounds(328, 139, 127, 25);
        rdbtnKidneys.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(rdbtnKidneys);


        JRadioButton rdbtnLungs = new JRadioButton("Lungs");
        rdbtnLungs.setBounds(328, 168, 127, 25);
        rdbtnLungs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(rdbtnLungs);


        JRadioButton rdbtnLiver = new JRadioButton("Liver");
        rdbtnLiver.setBounds(328, 199, 127, 25);
        rdbtnLiver.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        panel.add(rdbtnLiver);


        //Button Group 2
        ButtonGroup bg2= new ButtonGroup();
        bg2.add(rdbtnSkull);
        bg2.add(rdbtnHeart);
        bg2.add(rdbtnKidneys);
        bg2.add(rdbtnLungs);
        bg2.add(rdbtnLiver);
        // end of button group2
```

The code above is for just one question.

The counter should be at 1, when the user clicks the right answer. But if they click it multiple times, it will keep increasing.

Comment: Aren't you looking for simply changing the value to 1 instead of incrementing it?

Comment: I basically have a set of questions, and I want to count the number of correct questions answered. My problem here is that it increments on every click on a correct answer

Comment: In that case you can handle it in multiple ways. A simple one would be to have a boolean variable for each question. This way you could count the amount of correct questions and even track which questions were correctly answered

Comment: You mean count how many "true" variables are there, at the end?

Comment: Yes. It is not the fanciest way but it is simple enough to implement

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: Hey why don't you have a correctAnswerCounter too? and just ++ it, if the user answers correct answer, else only ++ the totalAnswersCounter

Comment: Yeah the thing is, it increments on every click. So, if the user clicks the correct answer multipe times, it will keep incrementing.
I only have a counter on the correct answers